# Can't install because provider name dollar_openBracket_applicationId_closeBracket

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-manifest

The error I get:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Package couldn't be installed in 
/data/app/com.name.android-1: Can't install because provider name 
dollar_openBracket_applicationId_closeBracket (in package com.name.android) 
is already used by com.name.alpha]
```

We have 3 versions of our application alpha, beta and stable. All have different bundle ids. Some time ago I could install all 3 on the same device (phone) without any problems. But now I can have only one of them installed at the same time. I have googled but couldn't find a solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked fine after i have updated these two packages to the following versions:

```
Xamarin.Facebook 4.4.0.2
Xamarin.Facebook.Android 4.24.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error (probably because of Firebase.Crashlytics):

```
INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER
Package couldn't be installed in [...]
Can't install because provider name dollar_openBracket_applicationId_closeBracket (in package [...]]) is already used by [...]
```

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/444), you need to update Xamarin.Build.Download:

1. Update the Xamarin.Build.Download Nuget Package to **0.4.12-preview3**

   - On Mac, you may need to check *Show pre-release packages* in the *Add Packages* window
2. Close Visual Studio
3. Delete all cached locations of NuGet Packages:

   - On Windows, open Visual Studio but not the solution:

     - Tools -> Option -> Nuget Package Manager -> General -> Clear All Nuget Cache(s)
   - On Mac, wipe the following folders:

     - `~/.local/share/NuGet`
     - `~/.nuget/packages`
     - `packages` folder in solution
4. Delete bin/obj folders in solution
5. Load the Solution
6. Restore Nuget Packages for the Solution (should run automatically)
7. Rebuild

Answer (score 0):

I use the Crashlytics package which generates the following duplicate lines in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<provider android:name="com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider" android:authorities="com.my.app.crashlyticsinitprovider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" />
<provider android:name="com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider" android:authorities="dollar_openBracket_applicationId_closeBracket" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" />
```

**"Quick fix" / Solution** I have for Fabric/Crashlytics to produce a production APK:

1. Rebuild your Android Project (this cleans the Bin/Obj folders and builds the project)
2. Go to `..obj/Release/90/lp/` (this folder contains more folders `0, 1, 2, 3, etc.`)
3. Find the folder with the Crashlytics `AndroidManifest.xml` file, which looks like this:

[image]
(You can probably use Notepad++ `Find in Files` for this step)

4. In the `aapt` folder, there is another `AndroidManifest.xml` file with contents:

   ```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.crashlytics.android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="2.9.4">

       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

       <application>
           <provider android:name="com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider" 
                 android:authorities="dollar_openBracket_applicationId_closeBracket" 
                 android:exported="false"
                 android:initOrder="100" />
       </application>

   </manifest>
   ```
5. Remove the entire `<application ... </application>` element and save the file.
6. `Build` or `Archive` your android project **(*Note:* Do not Rebuild)**
7. Success, the `dollar_openBracket_applicationId_closeBracket` line is gone.